# Texture stretching when applied to sphere

Tags: unity-game-engine, texture-mapping

I am completely new to this so I expect I may be doing something trivial incorrectly. I have a regular sphere in my Unity3D scene and I have a .jpeg image with a number in various places and orientations. When I apply the image to the sphere as a texture, the numbers centrally located in the image display fine on the sphere, but those closer to the top or the bottom of the image file appear warped on the sphere. For e.g with the number 12, the base of the 1 and 2 are bigger and the number tapers the further up you go when rendered on the sphere.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error on your part; this is the way the texture is mapped to a sphere by default.
To 'fix' this you would have to compensate that distortion in your texture directly *or* modify the UV coordinates of the sphere.